# Strange error in V3 Function App in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a V3 function app deployed to Azure, and on the OVERVIEW page I get this odd error message - **"System.Runtime.Extensions: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')."**

[image]

The function appears to be running and processing inputs, but if I go into FUNCTIONS, then I see another error message **"Azure Functions runtime is unreachable."**

[image]

Clicking on the ***"Functions runtime error"*** link in the Notifications section at the bottom of the OVERVIEW page does nothing - it doesn't provide any details on the error, or WHERE the error is being thrown.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the live stream log, to see if any exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Which language are you using? if your are using .netcore please have a look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2232)

Answer (score 1):

**There might be many causes that exist for this kind of errors `Azure Functions runtime is unreachable`:**

1. As mentioned in the troubleshooting steps of the above error in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account), the most common reason for this is that the function app has lost access to its storage account.

**One of the workaround I did here:**

Created the Azure Function (`.Net 3.1` Stack) - Premium Plan in the Azure Portal with HTTP Trigger, It is running successfully.

[image]

Below are the resources associated with this function app.

[image]

As stated in the above documentation to get that kind of runtime **unreachable** error, I deleted the storage account associated with this Function App.
[image]

After that deletion of the associated storage account, it has given the same error "`Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable`"

[image]

Recovered the deleted storage account and run the function again:

[image]

Make sure your storage account is not deleted which is associated with that function app, otherwise the function won't work.

2. Check the Storage account connection string to whether it is deleted or overridden. For example `AzureWebJobsStorage` is the local storage emulator connection string variable set in `local.settings.json` used in running the function locally. The same variable has a different value in the Azure portal used to run the function in azure. So, make sure that all the properties related to the storage account are available and correct.
3. If you set the firewall in the storage account and are not configured to allow traffic to and from functions, please allow it.
4. If your daily usage quota is full, then the function runtime will not work. To resolve this, increase or remove the daily quota limit and restart your function app. Otherwise, the execution of your function app is blocked until the next day.
5. Please check your function app has allowed your IP address in inbound IP restrictions, which might be configured to block internet access.
6. If your function is hosted in ***Internally load-balanced App Service Environment***, please check the internal IP address is allowed because you might be configured to block inbound internet traffic so that the `function runtime is unreachable`.
7. Make sure you set the correct value of `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` in Configuration (Application Settings) in the Azure Portal Function App as that is the function runtime version setting and refresh the function app/re-deploy the function.
   As I created the Function App of `.Net Core 3.1` Stack so the compatible function runtime version is **3**.

[image]